# javascript hotkey for button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searching for a time now but I did not find proper solution.

**What I am doing:** I have two keys <kbd>post bill</kbd> and <kbd>post and print</kbd>.

**What I want to do:** When I press <kbd>F7</kbd> then <kbd>post bill</kbd>(button) should be pressed and when <kbd>F8</kbd> then <kbd>post and print</kbd>(button) should be pressed.

I have seen `accesskey` function but it need <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> for it and it does not work with <kbd>F8</kbd> and it also have some oprationg system problem(different keys in every oprating system). Is there any JavaScript or jquery function to achive this task.

Any advice will be very helpful.

Comment: Did you try with .onkeypress ?

Comment: @HorsSujet that was the first thing I tryied.

Comment: Well, are you asking for F7, F8 or Alt ?

Comment: I don't understand that you need. What are the shorcuts that you need ?

Comment: @hex494D49 i just need f7 and f8 but when i used accesskey it needs alt with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this in JS, but you can capture key events and determine which keys are pressed to execute your logic on desired keys.

A good practice is to capture [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onkeyup) events on the DOM `document` with an listener attached via [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), e.g.:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.keyCode);
  switch(evt.keyCode) { 
    case 118 :                // key code for F7
      // your code
      break;

    case 119 :                // key code for F8
      // your code
      break;
  }
});
```